# Scala Implicit Conversion Gotchas

Tags: scala, conflict, implicit-conversion

**EDIT**
OK, @Drexin brings up a good point re: loss of type safety/surprising results when using implicit converters.

How about a less common conversion, where conflicts with PreDef implicits would not occur? For example, I'm working with JodaTime (great project!) in Scala. In the same controller package object where my implicits are defined, I have a type alias:

```
type JodaTime = org.joda.time.DateTime
```

and an implicit that converts JodaTime to Long (for a DAL built on top of ScalaQuery where dates are stored as Long)

```
implicit def joda2Long(d: JodaTime) = d.getMillis
```

Here no ambiguity could exist between PreDef and my controller package implicits, and, the controller implicits will not filter into the DAL as that is in a different package scope. So when I do

```
dao.getHeadlines(articleType, Some(jodaDate))
```

the implicit conversion to Long is done for me, IMO, safely, and given that date-based queries are used heavily, I save some boilerplate.

Similarly, for str2Int conversions, the controller layer receives servlet URI params as String -> String. There are many cases where the URI then contains numeric strings, so when I filter a route to determine if the String is an Int, I do not want to stringVal.toInt everytime; instead, if the regex passes, let the implicit convert the string value to Int for me. All together it would look like:

```
implicit def str2Int(s: String) = s.toInt
get( """/([0-9]+)""".r ) {
  show(captures(0)) // captures(0) is String
}
def show(id: Int) = {...}
```

In the above contexts, are these valid use cases for implicit conversions, or is it more, always be explicit? If the latter, then *what are* valid implicit conversion use cases?

**ORIGINAL**
In a *package object* I have some implicit conversions defined, one of them a simple String to Int:

```
implicit def str2Int(s: String) = s.toInt
```

Generally this works fine, methods that take an Int param, but receive a String, make the conversion to Int, as do methods where the return type is set to Int, but the actual returned value is a String.

Great, now in some cases the compiler errors with the dreaded ambiguous implicit:

> both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)
>   scala.collection.immutable.StringOps and method str2Int(s: String) Int
>   are possible conversion functions from java.lang.String to ?{val
>   toInt: ?}

The case where I know this is happening is when attempting to do manual inline String-to-Int conversions. For example, `val i = "10".toInt`

My workaround/hack has been to create an asInt helper along with the implicits in the package object: `def asInt(i: Int) = i` and used as, `asInt("10")`

So, is implicit best practice implicit (i.e. learn by getting burned), or are there some guidelines to follow so as to not get caught in a trap of one's own making? In other words, should one avoid simple, common implicit conversions and only utilize where the type to convert is unique? (i.e. will never hit ambiguity trap)

Thanks for the feedback, implicits are awesome...when they work as intended ;-)

Comment: Why call `"10".toInt` when you have an implicit conversion in scope?  You should `"10": Int` instead and let the implicit conversion take care of it.  (But I agree with drexin about this in general not being a good implicit to have in scope.)

Comment: I'm not calling "10".toInt, was an example. Where I was bitten was with, new JodaTime().toString("yyyy").toInt. I did not know re: "10": Int syntax, good to know. I edited my answer to show the context in which the implicits are used

Comment: Your question now doesn't contain a question.  Could you try editing again to state what you're having problems with?

Comment: to implicit or not to implicit, that is the question. My edit shows a bit more the context in which I am using implicit conversions. The replies so far have been, don't bother be explicit, so I'm wondering what are the "valid" use cases for implicits? Edited my question to reflect this

Comment: @virtualeyes Implicit conversions to add methods are ok (and inevitable). Implicit conversions to convert types are dangerous at best, and should be avoided. To put it simply, `JavaConversions` is bad, `JavaConverters` is good. They can be also used with builder-like patterns, such as in ScalaQuery, but, really, that is *another* question. Don't change the question, make a new one. It's free.

Comment: +1, it's becoming quite clear (since every reply has been to this affect): avoid direct type conversions; instead, go pimp-my-library a la Rex's JodaTime version of my implicit (although I can't think of a case where I pass a JodaTime instance to a method expecting a Long that is NOT part of the ScalaQuery DAL). Anyway, at the start better to not develop bad habits, so going to follow convention.  Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're mixing two different use cases here.

In the first case, you're using implicit conversions used to hide the arbitrary distinction (or arbitrary-to-you, anyway) between different classes in cases where the functionality is identical.  The `JodaTime` to `Long` implicit conversion fits in that category; it's probably safe, and very likely a good idea.  I would probably use the enrich-my-library pattern instead, and write

```
class JodaGivesMS(jt: JodaTime) { def ms = jt.getMillis }
implicit def joda_can_give_ms(jt: JodaTime) = new JodaGivesMS(jt)
```

and use `.ms` on every call, just to be explicit.  The reason is that units matter here (milliseconds are not microseconds are not seconds are not millimeters, but all can be represented as ints), and I'd rather leave *some* record of what the units are at the interface, in most cases.  `getMillis` is rather a mouthful to type every time, but `ms` is not too bad.  Still, the conversion is reasonable (if well-documented for people who may modify the code in years to come (including you)).

In the second case, however, you're performing an unreliable transformation between one very common type and another.  True, you're doing it in only a limited context, but that transformation is still liable to escape and cause problems (either exceptions or types that aren't what you meant).  Instead, you should write those handy routines that you need that correctly handle the conversion, and use those everywhere.  For example, suppose you have a field that you expect to be "yes", "no", or an integer.  You might have something like

```
val Rint = """(\d+)""".r
s match {
  case "yes" => println("Joy!")
  case "no" => println("Woe!")
  case Rint(i) => println("The magic number is "+i.toInt)
  case _ => println("I cannot begin to describe how calamitous this is")
}
```

But this code *is wrong*, because `"12414321431243".toInt` throws an exception, when what you really want is to say that the situation is calamitous.  Instead, you should write code that matches properly:

```
case object Rint {
  val Reg = """([-]\d+)""".r
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = s match {
    case Reg(si) =>
      try { Some(si.toInt) }
      catch { case nfe: NumberFormatException => None }
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

and use this instead.  Now instead of performing a risky *and implicit* conversion from `String` to `Int`, when you perform a match it will all be handled properly, both the regex match (to avoid throwing and catching piles of exceptions on bad parses) and the exception handling even if the regex passes.

If you have something that has both a string and an int representation, create a new class and then have implicit conversions to each if you don't want your use of the object (which you know can safely be either) to keep repeating a method call that doesn't really provide any illumination.

Comment: Excellent answer, Rex, thanks, that helps clarify the implicit conversion territory a bit more for me. The examples I've given are that of a beginner starting to explore, so good to know where I'm on track-ish (JodaTime) and way off (error-prone str2Int). I guess the general rule of thumb is: be explicit, and, if you are going to take the implicit route, do it in such a way so as to not baffle yourself (when you later return to the code) and others who may have to decipher your magic kingdom ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I try not to convert anything implicitly just to convert it from one type to another, but only for the pimp my library pattern. It can be a bit confusing, when you pass a String to a function that takes an Int. Also there is a huge loss of type safety. If you would pass a string to a function that takes an Int by mistake the compiler could not detect it, as it assumes you want to do it. So always do type conversion explicitly and only use implicit conversions to extend classes.

edit:

To answer your updated question: For the sake of readability, please use the explicit getMillis. In my eyes valid use cases for implicits are "pimp my library", view/context bounds, type classes, manifests, builders... but not being too lazy to write an explicit call to a method.

Comment: I'll +1 one that, the "play it safe" approach.

Comment: it's true, the implicit implementation examples I've given are that of laziness; getMillis and toInt are not overly taxing on the fingers, I know.